# How to scrape the content of this website correctly?

Tags: html, flutter, dart, web-scraping

I am new to web development and I don't know how to retrieve the content from 4 urls of the same website, I always get empty values. I am using flutter and the package [web_scraper: ^0.0.8](https://github.com/tusharojha/web_scraper)

I need to retrieve titles, images, descriptions and urls from the site, the pages I will navigate are:

https://datassette.org/revistas (Categories)

https://datassette.org/revistas/videogames (Select the language of magazines)

https://datassette.org/revistas/br-brasil (magazine (title, image and url))

https://datassette.org/revistas/acao-games/semana-em-acao-especial-games-no-1 (magazine title, description, image, url from pdf).

What is the .getElement method?

```
 /// Returns List of elements found at specified address.
  /// Example address: "div.item > a.title" where item and title are class names of div and a tag respectively.
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> getElement(String address, List<String> attribs) {
    // Attribs are the list of attributes required to extract from the html tag(s) ex. ['href', 'title'].



import 'package:web_scraper/web_scraper.dart';

class WebScraperHelper {

  static final webScraper = WebScraper('https://datassette.org');

  static Future<void> getData() async{

    if (await webScraper.loadWebPage('/revistas')) {

    // it prints the full html
    //print("getPageContent: ${webScraper.getPageContent()}");

      List<Map<String, dynamic>> images = webScraper.getElement(
          'img.width-full.wt-height-full.display-block.position-absolute',
          ['src']);

      List<Map<String, dynamic>> descriptions = webScraper.getElement(
          'h3.text-gray.text-truncate.mb-xs-0.text-body', ['title']);

      List<Map<String, dynamic>> urls = webScraper.getElement(
          'div > ul > li > div > a',
          ['href', 'title']);

    print("images: $images"); // print []
    print("descriptions: $descriptions"); // print []
    print("urls: $urls"); // print []

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours testing I found a way to retrieve all the data I need.

```
static Future<void> getMagazines() async {

    if (await webScraper.loadWebPage('/revistas/acao-games')) {

      List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = [];

      List<Map<String, dynamic>> titles = webScraper.getElement(
          'span.field-content > a',
          []
      );

      // adicionar somente  os mapas que tiverem dado no atributo title

      List<Map<String, dynamic>> urls = webScraper.getElement(
          'div.field-content > a',
          [ 'href']
      );

      List<Map<String, dynamic>> images = webScraper.getElement(
          'div.field-content > a > img',
          [ 'src']
      );

      for(int i=0; i < urls.length; i++){

        maps.add({
          "title": titles[i]["title"],
          "url" : urls[i]["attributes"]["href"],
          "image" : images[i]["attributes"]["src"],
        });

      }

      //print("TITLES: $titles");
      //print("URLS: $urls");
      //print("IMAGES: $images");
      print(maps.length);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't use that package, I'm more comfortable using Regular Expressions, here an example:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:_samples2/networking.dart';


// get Categories
const kUrlRevistas = 'https://datassette.org/revistas';

var regExp1 = RegExp(r'<a href="\/revistas\/\p{L}+">(\p{L}+)<\/a>', unicode: true);

class Revistas {
  static Future fetchRevistas () async {
    print('Start fetching...');
    return await NetService.getRaw(kUrlRevistas)
      .whenComplete(() => print('Fetching done!'));
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  var data = await Revistas.fetchRevistas();
  var matches = regExp1.allMatches(data);
  
  print(matches.map((e) => e.group(1)).toList());
}
```

Result:

```
Start fetching...
Fetching done!
[Diversas, Eletrônica, Informática, Videogames]
```

P.S.: You need read HTML code.

Comment: Could you please add your method "NetService.getRaw"? And about your code you retrieved only the categories names but I needed the category images and the urls too like "http://datassete.org/revistas/Videogames".